# Alternative to 30+ `| rex field=path mode=sed...` in order to replace path parameters in urls

Tags: splunk

I am composing a Splunk query to summarize AWS ELB access logs.  The purpose is to gather all the information needed to inform a load test that approximates production traffic.

Many of our URLs include path parameters.  For example, a directory component may be a GUID, or a user's account ID, etc.  In order to collapse all calls to a particular endpoint into a single string, I need to find and replace those path parameters with a string that represent the parameter.  For example: `/users/3h5l2h5fn1` becomes `/users/{accountId}`.  This is easy enough, I just use a sequence of `| rex field=path mode=sed` commands.

The problem I'm encountering is that about the time I hit 30 such commands, the query starts failing.  There's no clear indication why, the job just gets killed.

My question for the Stack Overflow experts is: Is there another way of doing a series of 50+ find-and-replace on the path field?  One that won't break Splunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sounds like a job for [`transforms.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Transformsconf) or maybe just to properly extract all those fields with [`props.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Propssconf).

If you're waiting until search time to mask data, you're still *storing* all of what you're trying to mask

Lastly, `eval myfield=replace(my_field,"regex","literal string")` is almost always faster, in my experience, than `rex mode=sed`

Doc.Splunk references for `eval`, `rex`:

- https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval

  - https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/TextFunctions#replace.28.26lt.3Bstr.26gt.3B.2C.26lt.3Bregex.26gt.3B.2C.26lt.3Breplacement.26gt.3B.29
- https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex

Comment: I'm not extracting the data, and I'm not masking it.  The raw logs still need to have the data, for debug purposes.  I'm just trying to summarize how many calls to a given endpoint, and for that, I have to be able to tell which is which.

Comment: I didn't know about the `replace()` function.  I'll transform my code to use that and see if that gets me past the apparent limit.  If it does, I'll mark your answer as solving my problem! :)

Comment: @JohnArrowwood - knowing that you're not masking it is good. But I *strongly* suspect you'll have even better performance if you extract those fields with `props.conf` - you can then do stats on those fields, which will *probably* be faster even than doing `eval replace()` ... something like this: `<search> | stats count by endpoint`

Comment: There we go.  40 find-and-replaces in a row, and the query doesn't choke on me.  Thanks!  I marked this as the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about `props.conf` but that wouldn't help me in this case.  To give an example, the request URL is something like `http://server/api/accounts/{accountId}` - except `{accountId}` is the actual account ID.  `stats count by url` would count each distinct account ID as a separate bucket.  I want all calls to that endpoint counted together.  Hence the need to find-and-replace the parameter values into parameter names.